# How can we add logo in the resume table?

Tags: minipage, logos

while preparing resume using latex.
trying to embed 4 things inside minipage like this

[image: expected output]
[image: download image or logo]

```
% LaTeX file for resume 
% This file uses the resume document class (res.cls)

\documentclass[margin]{res} 
% the margin option causes section titles to appear to the left of body text 
\textwidth=5.2in % increase textwidth to get smaller right margin
%\usepackage{helvetica} % uses helvetica postscript font (download helvetica.sty)
%\usepackage{newcent}   % uses new century schoolbook postscript font 

\begin{document} 




\begin{resume} 

\section{Experience}

% How to add Logo below \hspace{0.75\linewidth}\includegraphics[width=1.0\linewidth]{download.jpg}

{\bf System Consultant,} Fleet Van Lines, Bayridge, NY \hfill  Summer 1984
\begin{itemize} \itemsep -2pt %reduce space between items
\item Researched, implemented new computer accounting 
                 system 
\item Customized existing software for inventory 
                 management 
\item Trained employees on both accounting and inventory 
                 systems 
\end{itemize}


\end{resume} 
\end{document}
```

Or also, tried this 
but still cannot update the logo into the table !!!

```
% LaTeX file for resume 
% This file uses the resume document class (res.cls)

\documentclass[margin]{res} 
% the margin option causes section titles to appear to the left of body text 
\textwidth=5.2in % increase textwidth to get smaller right margin
%\usepackage{helvetica} % uses helvetica postscript font (download helvetica.sty)
%\usepackage{newcent}   % uses new century schoolbook postscript font 

\begin{document} 




\begin{resume} 

\begin{table}[h!]
  \begin{center}
  %  \caption{Multirow and -column table.}
    \label{tab:table1}
    \begin{tabular}{lSr}
      \textbf{Value 1} & \textbf{Value 2} & \textbf{Value 3}\\
      \hline
      \multicolumn{2}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{1234}} & a\\ % <-- Multicolumn spanning 2 columns, content multirow spanning two rows
      \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & b\\ % <-- Multicolumn spanning 2 columns with empty content as placeholder
      \hline
      \includegraphics[width=1.0\linewidth]{download.jpg} & fgrzhfergherulglhrugntkgntrgmntrg & c\\
      4 & 25.113231 & d\\
 & fhfhrjfrjh & \\
& frjhfrhflrg & \\
265623774 & & \\

    \end{tabular}
  \end{center}
\end{table}

\end{resume} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include a complete compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows what you tried so far. Probably a sketch of the desirec output would also be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for response. Will update the question in an hour with MWE

Comment: An MWE should compile if I copy-paste it into an empty file. For a LaTeX document, it should start `\documentclass{}` and end `\end{document}`. How is `\cvsection` defined for example?